# SignalR client try to run on the server side NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, signalr

I am trying to run Signalr client on the server side NodeJS. but i am getting bellow error. how can i resolve this issue?
Chat.js code

```
const signalR = require("@microsoft/signalr");

const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
  .withUrl("http://127.0.0.1:7265/chathub")
  .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
  .build();

const start = async () => {
  try {
    await connection.start();
    console.log("Connected to signal r hub");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
// starting the app
const startApp = async () => {
  await start(); // connection will stablised
};

startApp();
```

**I am getting error**

```
[2023-04-08T07:27:03.490Z] Error: Failed to complete negotiation with the server: FetchError: request to http://127.0.0.1:7265/chathub/negotiate?negotiateVersion=1 failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:7265
[2023-04-08T07:27:03.490Z] Error: Failed to start the connection: Error: Failed to complete negotiation with the server: FetchError: request to http://127.0.0.1:7265/chathub/negotiate?negotiateVersion=1 failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:7265
FailedToNegotiateWithServerError: Failed to complete negotiation with the server: FetchError: request to http://127.0.0.1:7265/chathub/negotiate?negotiateVersion=1 failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:7265
    at HttpConnection._getNegotiationResponse (/Users/user/Desktop/WebChat-Client-master/node_modules/@microsoft/signalr/dist/cjs/HttpConnection.js:256:35)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async HttpConnection._startInternal (/Users/user/Desktop/WebChat-Client-master/node_modules/@microsoft/signalr/dist/cjs/HttpConnection.js:172:41)
    at async HttpConnection.start (/Users/user/Desktop/WebChat-Client-master/node_modules/@microsoft/signalr/dist/cjs/HttpConnection.js:75:9)
    at async HubConnection._startInternal (/Users/user/Desktop/WebChat-Client-master/node_modules/@microsoft/signalr/dist/cjs/HubConnection.js:132:9)
    at async HubConnection._startWithStateTransitions (/Users/user/Desktop/WebChat-Client-master/node_modules/@microsoft/signalr/dist/cjs/HubConnection.js:109:13)
    at async start (/Users/user/Desktop/WebChat-Client-master/chat.js:10:5)
    at async startApp (/Users/user/Desktop/WebChat-Client-master/chat.js:18:3) {
  errorType: 'FailedToNegotiateWithServerError'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You told it to connect to `http://127.0.0.1:7265/chathub` and the connection is being refused.

Either:

- You forgot to run the server
- You got to the URL to the server wrong
- A firewall is blocking the connection (this is very unlikely for a localhost URL).

Run the server or correct the URL.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this was caused by Https Redirection. Try removing

```
 app.UseHttpsRedirection();
```

from your Program.cs on the server. Then try to connect like this

```
const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
.withUrl("http://localhost:5246/TestHub", {
    skipNegotiation: true,
    transport: signalR.HttpTransportType.WebSockets
})
.configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
.build();
```